# Is there a list of all connected $T_0$-spaces with 5 points?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Is there some place (on the internet or elsewhere) where I can find the number and preferably a list of all (isomorphism classes of) finite connected $T_0$-spaces with, say, 5 points?

In know that a $T_0$-topology on a finite set is equivalent to a partial ordering, and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order) tells me that there are, up to isomorphism, 63 partially ordered sets with precisely 5 elements. However, I am only interested in connected spaces, and I'd love to have a list (most preferably in terms of Hasse diagrams).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43069/is-there-a-list-of-all-connected-t-0-spaces-with-5-points).